# How to depict use cases shared by actors and how to document differences within those use cases

Tags: use-case, actor

i have 2 questions:

1. while creating a use case diagram, how do i depict use cases shared by multiple actors? how can i use'actor generalization' in this case? can i create a 'generic user' and reference the individual actors to this user?
2. Can use cases be used to depict differences in the same use case across multiple actors? Eg. An Agent and Manager can both Edit prospect information but the agent can only edit 3 fields as opposed to the manager who can edit 5 fields. am guessing such differences will be documented in a separate requirements section?

Answer (score 0):

> use cases shared by multiple actors?

Connect them with lines.  THere's no magic.  Any actor can be connected to any use case.

> can i create a 'generic user' and reference the individual actors to this user?

Yes.  It's regular inheritance.  There's no magic.  Ordinary open-headed "is-a" arrows for showing subclass-superclass work for actors and use cases just like the work for every other kind of classifier.

> Can use cases be used to depict differences in the same use case across multiple actors?

Yes, you have use case `<<extends>>` and use case `<<uses>>` relationships among use cases, also.  This is a common way to show that there's a general use case, extended in slightly different ways for different users.

Comment: Thanks. So would it be correct to create a generic use case (Edit Prospect information) and create an extended use case for just the additional feature and connect the actor who has the additional feature (manager in this case) to just the extended use case?

Comment: @Addy: Correct.  You're showing the relationships among the requirements.